# Git support for ANSI colors in default mac terminal

Tags: git

I modified default output of `git log`, to this:

```
git log --pretty=format:'- %C(#00C853)[%ad] %Creset%s' --date=format:'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'
```

[image]

In this format, default mac terminal does not display colors, but iTerm does.

As far as I understand, the problem is with rendering ANSI colors in default mac terminal.

Is there a way to make git support for ANSI colors?

Answer (score 2):

From git-config...

> Colors may also be given as numbers between 0 and 255; these use ANSI 256-color mode (but note that not all terminals may support this). ***If your terminal supports it, you may also specify 24-bit RGB values as hex, like #ff0ab3***.

I don't know how to get the Mac terminal to support Git's 24-bit RBG colors.

You can use the built in colors like `%Cgreen`. Or you can use the closest [256-color](https://jonasjacek.github.io/colors/) like `%C(35)`.

You can also turn on colors in general in your `.gitconfig`, though this has been the default since 1.8.4.

```
[color]
        # Turn on colors as applicable
        ui = auto
```